# What makes this chip-list fail in my Angular 14 and Angular material app?

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

I am working on a form in Angular 14.

I am trying to add a field with Angular Material cips.

In the component's Typescript file, I have:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,) { }

public visible: boolean = true;
public selectable: boolean = true;
public removable: boolean = true;
public addOnBlur: boolean = true;
public readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];

public myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    companyName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    countryName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

    businessLines: new FormGroup({
      businessLines: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
    }),
});


get businessLineControls(): FormArray {
    return this.myForm.get('businessLines') as FormArray;
}

 public add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our businessLine
    if ((value || "").trim()) {
      this.businessLineControls.push(this.fb.control(value));
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = "";
    }
}

public remove(businessLine: string): void {
    const index = this.businessLineControls.value.indexOf(businessLine);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.businessLineControls.removeAt(index);
    }
}
```

In the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" class="example-chip-list">
        <mat-label>Business lines:</mat-label>
        <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Delect business line" formArrayName="businessLines">
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let businessLine of businessLineControls.value" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
                (removed)="remove(businessLine)">
                {{businessLine}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">Cancel</mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
            <input placeholder="New business line..."
                 [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                 [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                 [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                 (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
        </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

#### The problem

For a reason I was unable to  understand, the console throws the error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables
```

It seem to happen here:

```
<input placeholder="New business line..."
  [matChipInputFor]="chipList"               
  [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
  [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
  (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
```

#### Questions

1. What causes this error?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix it?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link to check?

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring because you are trying to iterate over an object (FormArray) instead of an array. The "FormArray" class doesn't implement the Iterable interface.

To fix it, you can use the .controls property of the FormArray, which returns an array of its controls. So, in your template, replace:

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let businessLine of businessLineControls.value" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(businessLine)">
    {{businessLine}}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">Cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```

with:

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let businessLine of businessLineControls.controls; let i = index" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(i)" >
    {{businessLine.value}}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">Cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```

and in your remove function, change it to:

```
public remove(index: number): void {
    this.businessLineControls.removeAt(index);
}
```

Comment: Great! But this error message appeared twice and now aspers _once_ and that is a progress. But the error persists. :(

Answer (score 1):

Well... It's written in black and white, or more like in red and red :) You're passing an `object` into *ngFor directive somewhere. You haven't provided enough of your code to find a bug, at least I am not able to find one. Can you maybe prove a bigger chunk? At least that including `<mat-chip-grid #chipList>` and `mat-chip-row *ngFor="let var of list"`? Because the only iterable in your component is: `separatorKeysCodes` and `businessLineControls` getter.

If I were to shoot blindfolded I would assume that you've forgotten to put `controls` property into your `*ngFor`

```
// This is you'r code for *ngFor <mat-chip-row>
*ngFor="let businessLineControl of businessLineControls"

// This is how it should have been
*ngFor="let businessLineControl of businessLineControls.controls"
```

Comment: I have `ngFor="let businessLineControl of bussinessLineControls.value"` not `ngFor="let businessLineControl of bussinessLineControls"`